# How to directly get an object's description; the output of print(object)

Tags: python

If you do

```
print(object)
```

You get an description of that object.

How can I directly access this description?

I tried type(object), and object.**class** but they didn't get the same exact description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
object.__ str__()
```

is what you want. Alternatively

```
object.__repr__()
```

sometimes differs from

```
__str__
```

with more detail, but is generally more difficult to read.

Edit:

Needed to add `()` for method to give the description

Answer (score 1):

Use the Dunder Methods of the objects.

- obj.__repr__()
- obj.__str__()

or

- repr(obj)
- str(obj)

It depends on the object how and if this methods are implemented

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.ndarray()

print(arr.__repr__())
# prints: array([[1]])

print(arr.__str__())
# prints: [[0]]
```